# Magento2.4 How to add product to cart with a customizable option?

Tags: magento2, addtocart, phtml, customizable-options

I am trying to add a product to cart with a customizable option. I can add simple products, but I have not successfully been able to add a product with an option. The product will eventually be added dynamically but I just want a hard coded example right now to build off of.

**Custom options are:**
[image]

I would prefer just a simple objectManager example that will work in a phtml file to keep things simple and straight forward. But I will appreciate/accept any answer that works.

**My current code:**

```
$productId = 4;
$obj = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $viewModel->getLoadProduct($productId);
$cart = $obj->create('Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');    
$params = array();      
$params['qty'] = 10;
$params['product'] = $productId;
$options = array();
$options['title'] = 'Rustic';
$params['options'] = $options;
$cart->addProduct($product, $params);
$cart->save();
```

**I get this error:**

```
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): The product's required option(s) weren't entered. Make sure the options are entered and try again.
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the $params['title'] = ID of the option, instead of the label?

Comment: This is what was needed: $params[$optionTypeId] = $optionId; // 2 and 3 in my case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Wrong**

```
$options['title'] = 'Rustic';
```

**Right**

*Hard Coded:*

```
$options[2] = 3;
```

*Dynamic:*

```
$options[$optionTypeId] = $optionId;
```

The key: **2** is the optionTypeId.

The val: **3** is the optionId.

**Accessible by loading product by Id, ex:**

```
$loadedProduct = $viewModel->getLoadProduct($loadedProductId);
foreach ($loadedProduct->getOptions() as $options) {
            $optionData = $options->getValues();
            foreach ($optionData as $data) {
                $customizableOptions = $data->getData();
                print_r($customizableOptions);
            }
        }
```

**You can also add the product to the cart and Inspect the Form Data Headers to see the option ID's:**

[image]